# Cascading WHERE clause inside a VIEW with a UNION

Tags: mysql, view, union

### This isn't solved, but I found out why: [MySQL View containing UNION does not optimize well...In other words SLOW!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173688/)

---

Original post:

I'm working with a database for a game. There are two identical tables `equipment` and `safety_dep_box`. To check if a player has a piece of equipment I'd like to check both tables.

Instead of doing two queries, I want to take advantage of the UNION functionality in MySQL. I've recently learned that I can create a VIEW. Here's my view:

```
CREATE VIEW vAllEquip AS SELECT * FROM equipment UNION SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box;
```

The view created just fine. However when I run

```
SELECT * FROM vAllEquip WHERE owner=<id>
```

The query takes forever, while independent select queries are quick. I think I know why, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks!

P.S. with Additional Information:

The two tables are identical in structure, but split because they are multi-100-million row tables. 
The structure includes primary key on int id, multiple index on int owner.
What I don't understand is the speed difference between the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE owner=1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box WHERE owner=1) AS uES;
```

0.42 sec

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE owner=1 UNION  SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box WHERE owner=1) AS uES;
```

0.37 sec

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vAllEquip WHERE owner=1;
```

aborted after 60 seconds

---

Version: 5.1.51

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM equipment UNION SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box;
+----+--------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type  | table          | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra |
+----+--------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | equipment      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1499148 |       |
|  2 | UNION        | safety_dep_box | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  867321 |       |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2>     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    NULL |       |
+----+--------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
```

with a WHERE clause

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE owner=1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box WHERE owner=1
    -> ;
+----+--------------+----------------+------+-----------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type  | table          | type | possible_keys         | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+--------------+----------------+------+-----------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | equipment      | ref  | owner,owner_2,owner_3 | owner | 4       | const |    1 |       |
|  2 | UNION        | safety_dep_box | ref  | owner,owner_3         | owner | 4       | const |    1 |       |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2>     | ALL  | NULL                  | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |       |
+----+--------------+----------------+------+-----------------------+-------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? Could you show an explain of SELECT * FROM equipment UNION SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box; ?

Comment: I've addressed your 2 questions in my original post.

Comment: You need to EXPLAIN _with_ the WHERE clause.  Otherwise the execution plan is pretty obvious (get all the rows from one table, then the other).  With the WHERE clause, the EXPLAIN will (probably) tell you that it's getting a small number of rows from the first table then doing some kind of table scan on the second (possibly because of the missing UNION ALL as described below).

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN with the WHERE. This is the heart of the issue -- when I add a WHERE clause to the selection from the view -- it does not propagate to the internal SELECT statements. From what I've been able to find -- there's no solution around it other than not using a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should probably be using UNION ALL instead of plain UNION.  With plain UNION, the engine will try to de-duplicate your result set.  That is likely the source of your problem.

Secondly, you'll need indexes on owner in both tables, not just one.  And, ideally, they'll be integer columns.

Thirdly, Randolph is right that you should not be using "*" in your SELECT statement.  List out all the columns you want included.  That is especially important in a UNION because the columns must match up exactly and, if there's a disagreement in the column order in your two tables you may be forcing some type conversion to go on that is costing you some time.

Finally, the phrase "There are two identical tables" is almost always a tip-off that your database is not optimally designed.  These should probably be a single table.  To indicate ownership of an item, your safety_dep_box table should contain only the ownerID and itemID of the item (to relate equipment and players), and possibly an additional autonumbered integer key column.

Comment: I've added additional information to the original post to address the points you are making. I've also create a view that only selects id,owner,name and querying that view was also aborted after 60 seconds

Comment: What's the time for "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE owner=1 UNION  SELECT * FROM safety_dep_box WHERE owner=26990) AS uES;"?  Unless you mis-typed, you're not testing the SELECT against table equipment ? ownerID = 1.

Comment: Yeah, typo :(. I replaced the owner id to remove confusion, but instead I created some

Comment: The `union all` comment in this answer is the important part for your speed problem.  As he said, `union` includes an implicit de-dupe phase, which requires sorting and comparisons.  With 100+ million rows, that is going to be very, very slow.

Comment: But I tried UNION ALL and it didn't help >_<. The problem is that my WHERE clause does not propagate to the tables within the view, and the view tries to generate a temporary table containing the entirety of both tables. I don't know how to speed that up, other than not using a view

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use SELECT * in views ever. It's lazy code. Secondly, without knowing what the base tables look like, we're even less likely to be able to help you.

The reason it takes forever is because it has to build the full result and then filter it. You'll want indexes on your `owner` fields, whatever they may be.

Comment: SELECT * is because I want my view to have the same functionality as individual selection. I already have indexes on owner column, though it's not helping. The base tables have too many columns to list here, though I don't see how that would matter.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no excuse for using SELECT * in a view. Perhaps you need to look into an indexed view?

Comment: Is there a way to index a view in MySQL that i'm not aware of?